# what technology fit best to following scenario?

Tags: java, web-services, client-server

I have an idea for a smartphone application.the idea involves communicating with a web server in a specific protocol that I wish to design. what is the best architecture for the web server that fits this scenario, If I want to use DB pesistance, client server communication, and it should be in a language I'm farmiliar with, such as Java or c++?

I'm sorry if it's a noob question, I never dealt with this kind of development (I'm a RT embedded engineer)

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would pick a technology that is easy to deploy and manage. I'm not a C++ guy, but I think Java fits the bill.  There are a number of easy ways to deploy java these days:

1. Google App Engine: http://code.google.com/appengine/
2. Heroku:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java
3. Amazon ec2 beanstalk: http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Each of these will provision the servers and databases for you.  Google, and I think Heroku, have free plans for getting started.

-Dave

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is too broad.

I would go for what I'm most confident with, Unix server with Java and MySQL, but since you intend to create the protocol, anything would do, like Windows with SQL Server and IIS and .Net 4...

The fundamental idea is, since you intend to create the protocol, what you interface with is irrelevant. If you were going to use SOAP on a WinPhone, it would make sense to go for a .Net platform, whatever people might say about compatibility and SOAP. Similarly, Android would be better interfaced with Axis and Java, imho. The iPhone anyway requires third party tools or hand-coding of XML, so anything goes.

As it is, your initial idea is right: go for what you master best, because the field has enough learning requirements as it is that you don't need more hurdles :D